# php use switch without break;

Tags: php

whats wrong with my switch ? 
Now result:

```
< more
> less
= equality
!= no't equality
```

As it should be:

```
< more
= equality

<?php
$page = 99;

    switch ($page)
    {
        case $page < 121:
            echo '< more <br/>';
        case $page > 123:
            echo '> less <br/>';
        case $page == 99:
            echo '= equality <br/>';
        case $page != 99:
            echo '!= no\'t equality <br/>';
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: That's how `switch` works, without `break`. See [the docs](http://php.net/switch).

Comment: btw, `>` means "more" and `<` means "less". You seem to have these the wrong way around.

Comment: It’s either “no equality” or “not equal”; but “no’t equality” doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your switch statement you're comparing a number with boolean values.
Let's take the first case `$page < 121` is `true`, so the comparison taking place is `99==true` which is `true` according to http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling ([switch](http://docs.php.net/switch) performs a loose comparison, not a strict like [===](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.comparison)). Thus the first case block is executed.
And since you don't have a [break](http://docs.php.net/break) statement it falls through to the next case block and the next and so on...
Meaning: This won't work as intended regardless of whether you use `break` or not.

Comment: +1. Even with the `break`, the OP's code is wrong.  `switch` compares the `switch` value to the `case` value.  It does not look for true `case` values.  This is easy to see if you try 0.  It will (wrongly) start executing at the second, because `0 == (0 > 123)`, but `0 != (0 < 121)`.

Comment: Yes, `break` won't fix it... for clarity added to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

You don't seem to understand how switch works. What you want is a series of if statements, i.e.

```
        if ($page < 121)
            echo '< more <br/>';
        if ($page > 123)
            echo '> less <br/>';
        if ($page == 99)
            echo '= equality <br/>';
        if ($page != 99)
            echo '!= no\'t equality <br/>';
```

Answer (score 7):

Switch is to be used only when you want to compare a variable against a set of values.

```
switch ($variable)
{
   case "me":
       echo "variable is me";
      break;

   case "you":
       echo "variable is you";
       break;
   default:
      echo "Variable is neither of us";

}
```

The above switch case block can be written as shown below:

```
if ($variable=="me")
{
   echo "variable is me";
}
elseif ($variable=="you")
{
   echo "variable is you";
}
else
{
  echo "variable is neither of us";
}
```

DO NOT put an expression near the case statement.

```
switch ($somethng)
{
     case $something < 10:
      break;
     case $something > 20:

     break;
}
```

Switch is meant to be used only for comparing a variable against a set of values. ONLY! For everything else use a if...elseif..else statement.

The block above is wrong usage. Sometimes more than one of those expressions could be true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "cat";

switch($var)
{
  case "cat":
     echo 'My '.$var.' is called Bob.';
    break;
  case "dog":
     echo 'My '.$var.' is called James.';
    break;
  default:
     echo "I don't have an animal";
    break;
}
```

In a switch statemant you compare $var against value in a case. If there is a match, the actual case will be executed, otherwise the default will be executed. You can't use <>!=... in a case, only values like: 1, '1', 'dog', $var2, and so on.

If you want to run the same command for two case you can do:

```
$var = "cat";

switch($var)
{
  case "cat":
  case "dog":
     echo 'My '.$var.' is called James.';
    break;
  default:
     echo "I don't have an animal";
    break;
}
```

In your code, your forgot to put break; at the end of each case, that's why you see 'everything' in your output. And you miss default: too.

For the task you're doing, i suggest you to use if statements.

Answer (score 0):

if iam not wrong you can't use this characters < > raw in html. use instead the entities &gt; and &lt;.

if you run the script in the command line i got following output.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$page = 99;

switch ($page)
{
    case $page < 121:
        echo '< more <br/>';
    case $page > 123:
        echo '> less <br/>';
    case $page == 99:
        echo '= equality <br/>';
    case $page != 99:
        echo '!= no\'t equality <br/>';
}

$buffer = ob_get_clean();

echo str_replace('<br/>', "\n", $buffer);
```

output

```
< more 
> less 
= equality 
!= no't equality
```

which seems to be the correct behavoir.

> It is important to understand how the
>   switch  statement is executed in order
>   to avoid mistakes. The switch
>   statement executes line by line
>   (actually, statement by statement). In
>   the beginning, no code is executed.
>   Only when a case statement is found
>   with a value that matches the value of
>   the switch expression does PHP begin
>   to execute the statements. PHP
>   continues to execute the statements
>   until the end of the switch block, or
>   the first time it sees a break
>   statement.

http://de.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score -1):

';
            break;
        case $page > 123:
            echo '> less 
';
            break;
        case $page == 99:
            echo '= equality 
';
            break;
        case $page != 99:
            echo '!= no\'t equality 
';
            break;
        default: echo 'Default';
    }   
    ?>

Comment: Yup. Without a `break`, the `switch` will fall-through to the next `case`.

Comment: Plutov: `default` is not needed here, as it will never be reached, and `$page == 99` won't be reached either (either $page is < 121, or between 121 and 123 (then it's != 99), or > 123)

Comment: @Piskvor, this is only example.